# I am not able to install Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, rbenv

I am working on Ruby On Rails and whenever I try to install nokogiri-1.6.7.2, I get the following error:

---

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ext/nokogiri
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160607-19453-7k21kq.rb extconf.rb
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-8.2.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 8.2.2
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.7.2
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/https.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.0.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.0.0/lib/mini_portile2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:397:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/opt/gems/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/opt/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/opt/gems/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
```

---

Due to this Rails Server too is not starting and giving me error.. please help the results of the mkmf.log is below:-

---

```
"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby-static -framework CoreFoundation  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"clang -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe    -Werror -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

"clang -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -pipe  -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future   -Werror -c conftest.c"
error: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this.
Thanks

Comment: you have to install dependent libraries, search around web, you'll get it

Comment: I have used the dependent libraries and re-installed Ruby using Rbenv.. do you think I am using any particular dependent library??

Comment: which version on ruby and rails you are using. Also i expect you are using unix environment to execute these commands

Comment: @Bijendra The logs show Ruby 2.3.0 on Darwin (Mac OS X)

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually has nothing to do with nokogiri and more to do with rbenv (or specifically, ruby-build).

9 times out of 10, running `xcode-select --install` will fix the issue.  If that doesn't, I would suggest reviewing [this wiki article](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki) to make sure your build environment is properly configured.

If you need more help after that, I would suggest tagging your question with `rbenv`.  Personally, I stopped using it because of annoyances like this.

Comment: I did run xcode-select --install but that did not help ..if you have stopped using rbenv then what do you use?

Answer (score 0):

try to install nodes:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```